# MediaWiki uploads file path vs. "File:" URL

Tags: mediawiki, filepath

I have a mediawiki but for some reason the filepaths for uploads (which are disabled, i manually put the files i want in the images folder via ssh) are totally wrong

Im getting this: http://aaaa.com/bbb/index.php/File:Justgivingcms.jpg

When i should be getting this: http://aaaa.com/bbb/images/File:Justgivingcms.jpg (i assume)

I've had a scout about on the internet and changed a few settings/tried to change the filepath but nothing is working. Is there a specific setting anyone knows to specify the image filepath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://aaaa.com/bbb/index.php/File:Justgivingcms.jpg is a path to a file page, not to the file itself, and it looks perfectly normal (depending on you [short url settings](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aShort_URL)). compare with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:MediaWiki-smaller-logo.png